# What does the abbreviation f.a.a. stand for?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, terminology

I have recently encountered
$$u(t) \leq v(t) \color{red}{\text{ f.a.a. }} t \in [0, T]$$ for $u, v, \in L^2\big([0, T]; \mathbb{R}^n \big)$.

I am familiar with a.e. = almost everywhere, but couldn't find a (unique) definition for $\text{f.a.a.}$ . Out of the blue, I would guess that it means something like *for [almost all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all)*. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: Now I wonder if there is a place on MSE to collect common abbreviations, such as: iff, ae, as, iid... I'm not sure it would be on topic, but it would definitely be useful.

Comment: @Jean, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/common-acronyms-used-on-main-and-meta/3014#3014 isn't exactly what you want, but similar.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's what I had in mind, thank you! It might be better to distinguish mathematical acronyms and usual web acronyms (such as AFAIK), but it's still nice.

Comment: I think it would be more typical to write this as $u\leq v ~~\text{a.e in} [0,T]$, in the context of measure theory.

Comment: @K.defaoite Yes  agreed. My source is a paper on model predictive control, maybe this notation is more common for (optimal) control related fields.